# WS2016 Firewall: Still blocking program from sending packets after creating in/outbound rules for said application

Tags: windows-server-2016, windows-firewall

Starting config: Firewall has been set to block both in/outbound traffic by default. Minimal Core Networking rules have been enabled for NIC to get auto configured. Every other rule is disabled. So far this seems to work just fine.

Next, I added a program-specific rule both in and outbound to completely whitelist said program. Program still gets blocked.

Finally, I added a port-specific rule to just outbound to allow traffic on port 443. Poof, program can now send traffic. Before starting a transfer with said program, I started netstat in continuous mode to see what other application might be asking to send packets over 443 (which presumably would be why the program-specific whitelist wasn't sufficient). All I see in netstat are references to said program establishing connections over port 443.

What am I missing? I think I might be going nuts. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you rename the program and try the steps again of trying the program?  Not sure why it would help but gives another data point to try to diagnose...are you sure the port wasn't simply in use and the rogram wasn't able to bind to it the first time?

Comment: Yea, I'm not sure how that would cause it to fail, but I'll get a chance to try that out this weekend. I'll let you know how that goes.

As for the port being in use, considering the quantity of tests I did and the fact that the machine is doing virtually nothing outside of running the OS and this test I'd be surprised if that was the case.